# Simplifying lengthy result after integration with Maple

Tags: integration, maple

I want to integrate the following expression in Maple:

```
f := int(exp(-a*r^2)*exp(-b*r^2)*exp(-(r - R)^2*t^2)*r^2, r = 0 .. infinity):simplify(f, assume = positive);
```

The integration results in a very lengthy expression (as seen in the picture) which is too akward and unhandy for further integrations in maple.

[result of integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i69U.png)

How can I further simplify the result? Or attain a simple result (at least without the error function).

Thanks for the help!